# Query amount transferred after account merge operation

Tags: operations

I need to check the amount of LMX that were transferred to the destination account after an account merge operation.
But when checking the list of operations for the destination account, the related operation doesn't show the amount that was transferred.

How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

To find the amount, you need to look at the effects: https://developers.stellar.org/api/resources/effects/

You can look them up by operation: [https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/{operation}/effects](https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/%7Boperation%7D/effects)

Or by transaction:
[https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions/{transaction}/effects](https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions/%7Btransaction%7D/effects)

You can also use a block explorer like stellar.expert.  Just search for the transaction hash and click the double carrots to expand the operations.  You should see something like this:
[image]

The "amount credited" will show you how much was merged into the account.